# How to verify a self-signed root CA certificate along with a wildcard certificate against a server?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain, self-signed-certificate

I am using a local DNS server `192.168.1.1` which can resolve the local domain `custom.local` and all its subdomains. That by itself works fine.

In order to establish secure connections I have a self-signed root CA certificate looking like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

A wildcard certificate for `*.custom.local` that looks like this:

```
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 01 00 00 00 
    friendlyName: Wildcard custom.local
    ...: ... 
    ...: ... 
subject=C = ..., ST = ..., L = ..., O = ..., OU = IT, CN = *.custom.local, emailAddress = ...
issuer=DC = local, DC = custom, CN = CUSTOM-ROOT-CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And a private key for the wildcard certificate that looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to validate the combination of these three components and this is how I have been doing it so far:

```
# Check if the given private key belongs to the given wildcard certificate by comparing their derived public keys
[ "$(openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in ./CUSTOM_WILDCARD.crt)" = "$(openssl rsa -pubout -outform PEM -in ./CUSTOM_WILDCARD.key 2&> /dev/null)" ]

# Verify the trust chain of the wildcard certificate by checking if it was signed by the private key corresponding to the given root CA certificate
openssl verify -CAfile ./CUSTOM_ROOT_CA.crt ./CUSTOM_WILDCARD.crt
```

But this has a huge disadvantage, or maybe I should say that an important piece is missing. I'm never checking these certificates/key against the actual server and I'm wondering how this can be done.
Let's say I want to test it against `test.custom.local:443`. How would I do that?
Do I just connect using `openssl s_client -connect -CAfile ... -cert ... -key ...` and if it exits with code 0, I know that the certificates and key I have locally are the correct ones for that server/domain?

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect test.custom.local:443 -CAfile ./CUSTOM_ROOT_CA.crt -cert ./CUSTOM_WILDCARD.crt -key ./CUSTOM_WILDCARD.key
```

It appears to work at first glace, but if for example I change the last letter in the key file, the command still returns the same output with exit code 0, which makes me think that this method might not be safe.

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect -CAfile ... -cert ... -key ...` You seem to be conflating client certificates and server certificates here.  I don't see you mentioning mTLS, so I suppose you don't mean to provide client certificates.  Ignoring mTLS cases, your test should omit `-cert` and `-key`; the *server* cert will be sent from the server, it's private key is of course kept private on the server side, and the CA cert is all that's required to verify it.

Comment: @erik258 Thank you, that makes sense. So the client never needs the server's private key to connect to it and just by passing the root CA certificate, you tell openssl that you trust all certificates that have been signed by it, meaning that if the server's certificate was indeed signed by the given root CA certificate, the command would succeed. And checking if the certificate the server returns is the same as the local wildcard certificate, would be kinda redundant.

Comment: Correct.  Further, that's probably why you changing the (client side) private key had no effect.  TLS includes a mechanism for client keys and certs, but since there's no client "common name" (just a source IP address), TLS can't handle the validation like it can with a server cert that corresponds with an address (`test.custom.local`).  The server isn't configured to care about the client cert, so having a non matching key is inconsequential.